# Hover not removing styling on mouseoff

Tags: css

I have an video that moves on hover:

```
.video:hover {
 z-index: 5;
 transform: translate(1vw, -1vh);
}
```

The video shifts when I hover over it, and shifts back when I mouse off it. However, if I mouse off to the left, the video does not shift back. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Note: this only happens if you mouse off slowly (and to the left, of course).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maknel/5q6fwoug/)

Comment: Please share your problem in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: can you please create a fiddle or snippet ?

Comment: The box shadows is Considered part of the video. The solution is You can add an object like a hidden line with a shadow under the video.
then you show this line in .video:hover {

Comment: If you can't recreate in JSFiddle, then I would say there is a high likelihood that the problem lives somewhere else in your code.  Try your best to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to get the most meaningful assistance from the community.

Comment: there is no problem with your fiddle i think

Comment: I can't see the problem in fiddle which you describe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you are moving the very element that's triggering the move. You need to wrap your `.video` in one more div (called `.video-wrapper`).

Then you can use `.video-wrapper:hover .video` to move the inner element.

Also, it didn't work before because you forgot the comma between the x, y values.

```css
.cell {
  height: 20vw;
  border: 0.5vh solid #5776b9;
  width: 35vw;
}

.fit {
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
}

.video-wrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  margin:2vw;
}

.video-wrapper:hover .video {
  transform: translate(1vw, -1vh);
}
```

```html
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <div class="video cell">
   <video class="fit" controls>
     <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you missing `,` in your code :

**Change:**

```
transform: translate(1vw -1vh);
                        ^-------------------
```

**To:**

```
transform: translate(1vw,-1vh);
                        ^--------------------
```

```css
.cell {
 height: 20vh;
 border: 0.5vh solid #5776b9;
 width: 35vw;
}

.fit {
width:100%;
}
.video {
  width:200px;
  height:150px;
}

.video:hover {
 transform: translate(1vw ,-1vh);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="video cell">
     <video class="fit" controls>
       <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, that's why the fiddle wasn't working. Thank you, that was dumb of me.